# passing params to indices of an array in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm collecting user input via forms and trying to combine the values into an array variable in my controller.

controller

```
MyController < ApplicationController
  def con_action
   @array_var = Array.new(n)
   @array_var[index] = params[:user_input]
  end
end
```

view

```
<%= form_for :doesntmatter do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_input, placeholder: 'input for index 0'

    <%= f.text_field :user_input, placeholder: 'input for index 1'
<% end %>
```

also the array.size is always changing so making it dynamic is ideal.

I edited it so it makes more sense, my problem is that I won't know which index of the array that :user_input belongs to and need to have the form provide that index number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in you view, use this

```
    <%= form_tag(controller: : MyController, action: : con_action) do %>
       <%5.time do |n|%>
    <%= text_field_tag "user_input_"+n.to_s, nil,placeholder: "something" %>
       <%end%>
    <%submit_tag%>
    <%end%>
```

then in your controller you will get what you want in the params
use the  to_i function to convert to integer

```
    def con_action
      @array_var = Array.new(n)
       5.times do |n|
       @array_var[n] = params['user_input_'+n.to_s]
      end
     end
```

P.S. make sure you have a post route for mycontroller#con_action

Comment: thanks but the issue for me is how do i specify which index it is dynamically. I won't always know how many indices to set, so I can't hard code it into the controller such as `@array_var[index]`

Comment: U want to take the indice as an input from user, right?

Comment: no for this example the :user_input == "some string", and in the controller `index` is a value i need passed from the form.

Comment: What you are doing is creating a new array everytime the form is submitted. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: example : 
    `array = [nil, nil, nil]`
     `array[0] = :user_input`
     `array[1] = :user_input`

Comment: I think what u should do is create a model and add every user_input as an entry to that model

Comment: Your current code is simply creating a new array for every form submission

Comment: I see your confusion, I tried to simplify the question so its not so much to read. let me try to clarify to you. I have forms where users will input answers, and I have a submit button to render a new controller action that will compare user answers to correct answers... the correct answers are already hard coded and i just need to consolidate the user answers into an array to compare it.

Comment: I thinks this is the solution you are looking for, you can add the index to each form field and then use the same loop in the controller to get the correct form value corresponding to the index

Comment: @WolfgangTruong see the last edit on my answer,, this should solve ur problem

Comment: yes i'm implementing it into my code to see if it works now

Comment: UPDATE: yes after much rearranging I have it working. thanks Pranav!